# linux c compile with ftw library

Tags: c, linux

i have simple code:

```
  1 #include <ftw.h>
  2 #include <stdio.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 #include <string.h>
  5
  6 static int display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf){
  7     printf("%-3s %2d %711d  %-40s %d %s\n", tflag == FTW_D) ? "d" :
  8         (tflag == FTW_DNR) ? "dnr" : (tflag == FTW_DP) ? "dp" : (tflag == FTW_F) ? "f" :
  9         (tflag == FTW_DP) ? "dp" : (tflag == FTW_SL) ? "sl" : (tflag == FTW_SLN) ? "sln" : "?", ftwbuf->level, (long long) sb->st_size, fpath, ftwbuf->base, fpath + ftwbuf->base);
 10         return 0;
 11 }
 12
 13 int main (int argc, char ** argv){
 14     int flags = 0;
 15     if( argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'd') != NULL) flags |= FTW_DEPTH;
 16     if( argc > 2 && strch(argv[2], 'p') != NULL) flags |= FTW_PHYS;
 17     nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, flags);
 18
 19     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 20 }
```

and when i would like to compile:

```
gcc -o main main.c
```

i get some problems:

```
main.c:8: błąd: `FTW_DP, undeclared (first use in this function)
```

How i must compile (with some library or what?)

Comment: +1 this does not deserve a down vote, though it could be phrased better this is a valid problem with a non trivial solution. Perhaps an experienced C programmer would work this out easily enough but not everyone is such.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
```

to the top of your code.

Here is a nice reference page:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftw.3.html

Comment: Or alternatively, define at compile time `gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 solutions :

1. Above `#include <ftw.h>`, add :

   ```
   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
   #include <ftw.h>
   // ...
   ```
2. (thx @alvits) In command line, add :

   ```
   gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 ...
   ```
3. Into your makefile :

   ```
   CPPFLAGS := -D_OXPEN_SOURCE=500 ...
   ```

---

Why do you need this define ?

From inside `<ftw.h>` and then `<features.h>` you can see :

```
#ifdef  _XOPEN_SOURCE
...
# if (_XOPEN_SOURCE - 0) >= 500
#  define __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED  1
```

And in `<ftw.h>` :

```
#ifdef __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED
/* These flags are only passed from the `nftw' function.  */
  FTW_DP,       /* Directory, all subdirs have been visited. */
# define FTW_DP  FTW_DP
```

Comment: Or alternatively, define at compile time `gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 ...`.